# How to find the derivative of an output in Laplace domain

Tags: laplace-transform, signal-processing

I have a $Y(s)=F(s)\cdot X(s)$. Because it is a close feedback loop, I know F(s), but didn't compute the inverse Laplace transform of it because I don't know if $y(t) = f(t) \cdot x(t)$. The input x is a "known value" but it could be a constant or a function of time. However, the problem I am solving requires me to find the Laplace transformation of the derivative of y(t). But I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [basic tutorial and quick reference guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and enhance your question

Comment: HINT: $$\mathcal{L}(f')(s)=s\cdot \mathcal{L}(f)(s)-\lim_{z\to 0^-}f(z)$$

Comment: but I don't know what the x(t) would be and I can't just say $sY(s)=\frac{dy}{dt}=s \cdot F(s) \cdot X(s)$, right?